# Is it OK to post animated .gif's in answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, images

I haven't seen any answers supported with animated .gif's to convey an interaction.  I'm hesitant to post one if it has already been deemed as polluting the answers field.

The only .gif reference I see in meta has to do with community promotions. If this has already been covered, please post a reference.

**What is the consensus on posting animated .gif's to support an answer?**

Comment: I don't think I've ever, anywhere posted an animated gif of a cat doing something random, and I'll refrain from doing so here, but somewhere in the back of my mind that seems to be the perfect response to this question :) But really, if a GIF can help you explain something... why not? As long as the file-size isn't exorbitant, it shouldn't hinder anyone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It hasn't been a problem (in fact I'm not sure I've ever seen it done). It should be fine as long as it's completely relevant to the answer/question (like any image)and it's not overly distracting. I would only use it when it is useful in answering the question and displays some form of interaction or whatever that can't be easily/effectively expressed in words or static images.

In general I'd say go ahead, and if it proves too annoying then we'll decide on some rules regarding animation on Meta.

Comment: I don't know about other users but I happened to post a [GIF in one question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52115/how-to-present-a-todo-list-checklist-to-a-user). :)